# xcode error internal error. Xcode version 4.2.1

Tags: xcode4.2

> Internal Error Xcode encountered an internal logic error.
>
> ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-1938/Framework/Utilities/IBFoundationAdditions.m:141
>
> Details:  Assertion failed: originalMethod != ((void*)0)
>
> Function: void IBMethodSwizzle(Class, SEL, SEL)
>
> Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}
>
> Hints:   None
>
> Backtrace:
>       0  0x0000000101a525a1 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)    1  0x00000001010bb774 _DVTAssertionHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)
>       2  0x00000001010cd1a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)    3  0x0000000103ead152 IBMethodSwizzle (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)    4  0x00000001043dc836 -[IBCocoaPlugin init]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)    5  0x00000001043dbfbb
>   +[IBCocoaPlugin ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
>       6  0x00000001015d18bc _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
>       7  0x00000001015d160d *IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
>       8  0x00000001015d10cc IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
>       9  0x000000010194dc18 -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] (in IDEKit)    10  0x00007fff8ba15216
>   _*-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 (in Foundation)
>   11  0x00007fff845e32aa _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)    12 
>   0x00007fff8b91417b -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)    13 
>   0x00007fff86c0b819 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] (in AppKit)
>       14  0x00007fff86c0b3e5 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)    15  0x00007fff86c0433d NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)    16 
>   0x0000000101061eec (in Xcode)    17  0x0000000000000002

I'm trying to reinstall xcode.

Comment: Yep, I'm experiencing the same crash on a clean install of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Lion Gold Master or Lion Retail?  Apparently the latest Xcode only works with Lion Retail.